# Java Base64.getDecoder().decode() c# equivalent

Tags: java, c#

I have some java code that cannot be changed. I am trying to match the output from the Java code with some C# code. The password from the Java code is going through the `Base64.getDecoder().decode` produce. Some of the java out put has negative numbers but I am not getting any negative numbers in the C# code.
I have some java code:

```
String plaintextsalt = salt;
byte[] plainsalt = plaintextsalt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// The output from plainsalt is : [107, 104, 99, 101, 67, 82, 101, 115, 72, 54, 102, 106, 114, 86, 100, 122]
byte[] data = (Base64.getDecoder().decode(plainsalt));
// The output from data is : [-110, 23, 30, 9, 23, -84, 31, -89, -29, -83, 87, 115]
```

While my C# code produces :

```
String plaintextsalt = salt;
byte[] byteplainsalt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintextsalt);      
// The output from byteplainsalt is : [107, 104, 99, 101, 67, 82, 101, 115, 72, 54, 102, 106, 114, 86, 100, 122]      
byte[] data =  Convert.FromBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainsalt));
//output from data: [146, 23, 30, 9, 23, 172, 31, 167, 227, 173, 87, 115]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has signed bytes by default. In C#, bytes are considered unsigned. Any value above `127` would have been negative in the Java equivalent. If you need signed bytes, you'll need to convert the array to `sbyte`, eg:

```
var random = new Random();
var bytes = new byte[100];
var sbytes = new sbyte[bytes.Length];
random.NextBytes(bytes);
for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    sbytes[i] = (sbyte)bytes[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`byte` in C# is unsigned, so it cannot be negative. I don't know java, but it appears it's `byte` is signed. The following code will give you the same output from java. It casts the bytes as signed bytes:

```
sbyte[] data =  Convert.FromBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteplainsalt)).Select(x=>(sbyte)x).ToArray();
```

Also note that you're converting a string to `byte[]` and then back to string, so you can use the string directly:

```
sbyte[] data =  Convert.FromBase64String(plaintextsalt).Select(x=>(sbyte)x).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd consider using `x => unchecked((sbyte)x)` in case this is executing in a checked context, and to make it explicit that overflows are expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't change the Java code.

Comment: @user2697296 Note that the jave code needs the byte array for the conversion, C# doesn't, that's why I posted the second solution. But if you want the code just like the java, you can still use the first code fragment that I posted.

Comment: Just making a comment that the java code can't be changed. Again thank  you for your answer it worked perfectly.