# Converting unicode chars like 0x00 to bytes

Tags: java, c#, unicode, encoding

I am trying to port small library from Java to C#.
I encountered problem during conversion of unicode strings to the bytes. This can be displayed by snippets below:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {


   public static void method(String x){
        System.out.println(x);
        byte[] bytes = x.getBytes();
         for (byte z : bytes) {
            System.out.println(z);
        }
        System.out.println("Array length: "+bytes.length);
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
         method(""+(char)0xEE+(char)0x00+"testowy wydruk");

   }
}
```

This will do 3 things:

1. print string
2. get bytes
3. print that array + its length

I rewrote this snippet to C#:

```
 string x = "" + (char)0xEE + (char)0x00 + "testowy wydruk";
 Console.WriteLine(x);
 byte[] d = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x);
 foreach(byte z in d)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(z);
 }
 Console.WriteLine("Array length: "+d.Count());
```

Don't know why in Java Array has  17 elems and in C# it has 16.

difference is in first elements of bytes arrays:

[image: Java:]

Unfortunately this differences can cause a problems later because this array is being sent to another api.

Comment: Java bytes are signed, C# are unsigned. [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228551/java-base64-getdecoder-decode-c-sharp-equivalent/55228775#55228775)

Comment: Don't use Ascii Encoding it will filter non printable characters.

Comment: @Magnetron thanks! After adding conversion to sbyte it is working.

Comment: Java's `String.getBytes()` behaves differently from system to system, user to user and time to time. Is that what you want to emulate or is is a defect in the original code?

Answer (score 2):

`(char)0xEE` is `î`, aka [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH CIRCUMFLEX' (U+00EE)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ee/index.htm), which is encoded to UTF-8 as `0xC3 0xAE`, aka `-61 -82`.

Your Java code doesn't specify which encoding you wanted the bytes in, so Java apparently converted to UTF-8 for you (default varies by installation).

You explicitly specified `ASCII` in the C# code, so the `EE` character was converted to `?`, aka `0x3F` aka `63`, since there is no such character in ASCII.

If you change Java code to use [`getBytes("ASCII")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.lang.String-) or [`getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-), then you get same result as C#.

Comment: That's a relief. For a second there I though the answer would amount to "C# tries to emulate C and it adds the two chars \xEE and \x00 together, resulting in one char with value \xEE".